# tabularray: Selectively print some rows from a table stored in a macro

Tags: tables, tabularray

How can I print some rows out of the table stored in `\MyTable`?

For example, I need to print two groups of `rows = 1 to 3` and `rows = 6 to 8` in two ways:

1. print all the six rows as a whole without visual separation
2. print a separating row between the two groups spanning the two columns with some centered titled (e.g. `second part`)

```
begin{filecontents*}{mytable.tex}
1  &  11  \\
2  &  12  \\
3  &  13  \\
4  &  14  \\
5  &  15  \\
6  &  16  \\
7  &  17  \\
8  &  18  \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor, catchfile}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef{\MyTable}{mytable.tex}{}

\begin{tblr}[ long, expand = \MyTable ]{ 
        row{odd} = {gray!10},
        row{even} = {white},
        row{1} = {white},
        colspec = {X S} 
    }
    \toprule[1.5pt]
    One & {{{Two}}}  \\
    \midrule
    \MyTable
    \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a partial solution: it is not good enough, but at least it works.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.tex}
1  &  11  \\
2  &  12  \\
3  &  13  \\
4  &  14  \\
5  &  15  \\
6  &  16  \\
7  &  17  \\
8  &  18  \\
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor, catchfile}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef{\MyTable}{mytable.tex}{}

\newcommand\HideIt[1]{}

\begin{tblr}[ long, expand = \MyTable ]{ 
        row{odd} = {gray!10},
        row{even} = {white},
        row{1} = {white},
        colspec = {X S},
        stretch = 0,
        rowsep = 4pt,
        row{5-6} = {cmd=\HideIt,rowsep=0pt},
    }
    \toprule[1.5pt]
    One & {{{Two}}}  \\
    \midrule
    \MyTable
    \bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer; may I know the possible problems or limitations of your solution?

Comment: @Diaa (1) You need to set `stretch=0` and modify `rowsep` and the result may be slightly different from the original table. (2) you need to put `\HideIt` line after `colspec` since `S` columns also modify `cmd` option.

Comment: Could it be considered in the future if I create a feature request of this on GitHub?

Comment: @Diaa There might be some general interfaces for modifying the contents of tables in the future. I haven't decided how to implement them yet. It is rather complicated.

Answer (score 4):

This may not be the answer you hoped for, anyways:

Is there a reason why you don't use the `datatool` package that comes with a lot of nice functions that are built for exactly this purpose?

In case the first column of your file always contains the row numbers, you could do the following:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytable.tex}
1  &  11  \\
2  &  12  \\
3  &  13  \\
4  &  14  \\
5  &  15  \\
6  &  16  \\
7  &  17  \\
8  &  18  \\
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tabularx, colortbl, xcolor, booktabs}

\newcolumntype{S}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\DTLsetseparator{&}
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{mytable}{mytable.tex}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X S }
    \toprule
    \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two} 
    \DTLforeach*[\DTLisSubString{1,2,3,6,7,8}{\coli}]{mytable}{%
        \coli=Column1, \colii=Column2}{%
        \DTLiffirstrow{\\ \midrule}{\\}%
        \DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{gray!10}}{\rowcolor{white}}%
        \coli & \DTLsubstituteall{\colii}{\\}{}\colii %
    } \\ %
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `datatool` package is easier to handle with CSV data, but with some minor adjustments, you can also use it with TeX-formatted data: With `\DTLsetseparator{&}` you can change the column separator to the TeX-like `&`, and `\DTLsubstituteall{\colii}{\\}{}\colii` is needed to delete the double-slash from the end of each line to avoid additional empty rows in the table.

Due to the functionality of the `datatool` package, there is not even the need to use the `tabularray` package. I did not test whether the `datatool` package and the `tabularray` package are compatible. Since I avoided using the `tabularray` package, I used other packages to get a hopefully very similar styling of the table.

---

**Update**

In case that the table does not provide a column with an index or the row numbers, the most feasable way would be to first append another column that contains the row numbers (that is, the index) and which can be later used for filtering.

Sadly, the `datatool` package does not provide an index counter that can be used in the conditional for filtering via the `\DTLforeach` macro directly. As far as I understood, the package only provides an internal counter (`\DTLcurrentindex`) that can only be used in the body of `\DTLforeach` but not in the conditional (where we would need it), and then, there are others (`DTLrowi`, `DTLrowii` and `DTLrowiii`) that only count the rows after filtering.

In the following example I changed the last entry of the table to values that differ from the row index to illustrate that filtering is not done via these values,

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytable.tex}
1  &  11  \\
2  &  12  \\
3  &  13  \\
4  &  14  \\
5  &  15  \\
6  &  16  \\
7  &  17  \\
9  &  19  \\
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{tabularx, colortbl, xcolor, booktabs}

\newcolumntype{S}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\DTLsetseparator{&}
\DTLloaddb[noheader]{mytable}{mytable.tex}

% appending index column
\DTLforeach{mytable}{}{
    \DTLappendtorow{ID}{\DTLcurrentindex}
}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X S }
    \toprule
    \textbf{One} & \textbf{Two} 
    \DTLforeach*[\DTLisSubString{1,2,3,6,7,8}{\id}]{mytable}{%
        \id=ID, \coli=Column1, \colii=Column2}{%
        \DTLiffirstrow{\\ \midrule}{\\}%
        \DTLifoddrow{\rowcolor{gray!10}}{\rowcolor{white}}%
        \coli & \DTLsubstituteall{\colii}{\\}{}\colii %
    } \\ %
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

As before, filtering is done with `\DTLisSubString{1,2,3,6,7,8}{\id}` where the numbers represent the indices of the rows that should be printed. This would about be what you wanted initially, at least the first part of it.

Note that the starred version of `\DTLforeach` is read-only, which is why I only used it for the second iteration. Since we need to edit the database for appending the index column, the non-starred version of the macro is used.

Comment: My tables never have row numbers in the first column; it is just accidental :). I haven't tested your solution for a general use but I hope you proposed a general solution not for this specific MWE.

Comment: Of course this proposal is based on your MWE, since this is the only information I have. Since I don’t know how you will use it, it is hard to tell, whether my suggestion is rather general or not. It may fit your needs or not. Only you can tell …

Comment: It should work, as long as the rows have some kind of ID which you can use to select them.

Comment: Isn't there any internal counter for the rows you can depend on instead of relying on this explicit input from me? I am not expert to discuss something like this, so I am just wondering.

Comment: Sadly, there isn't. There is one internal counter that can only be used in the body of `\DTLforeach` but not in the conditional where we would need it, and then, there is another one that only counts the rows after filtering. However, I came up with a solution that appends an index column to the data which is then used for filtering.

Comment: @Diaa Sorry, I still have not found a way how to insert an additional row to separate two groups. I fear this is a lot more tricky than the question about selecting based on row index.

Comment: Never mind, I greatly appreciate your consideration.

Comment: Would you please apply your update to my MWE approach of using `tabularray` since I didn't manage to do so?

Comment: @Diaa Do you really need this? Because of the very different way `tabularray` works, it is probably very compicated and may even not be possible at all. I rather thought of the use of the `datatool` package as alternative for `tabularray`, since you can also include data from another macro into a table, which I thought is what you wanted.

Comment: It's OK. I just thought that tabularray is structurally close to the standard tabular. I can leave the question as it is for future.

Comment: The problem is, it seems, that the `expand` option only allows you to expand a macro one time. After this one expansion, `tabularray` needs to see all `&`  and `\\​` in order to correctly process the output. But only one expansion would not be enough to create the whole table using the `datatool` package. I am currently not sure how to solve this problem.